# Guice equivilent to Spring's BeanPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, guice

With Spring it's possible to add `BeanPostProcessor` implementations to the context in order to conditionally replace, wrap or proxy beans before and after they've been initialized with their dependencies.

Does Google Guice offer something similar?

***Example:** I have a `SomethingHandler` interface with a single `execute` method and based on some conditions I want to decorate / wrap implementations with `LoggingHandler`, `AuthenticationHandler` and so on.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use an InjectionListener

http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/spi/InjectionListener.html

more on the subject:

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=62

Comment: Thanks! Man, that's a verbose api even for Java :-)

Comment: I really like it. I actually prefer it to Spring, where you are facing XML-hell sooner or later...

Comment: I prefer Guice over Spring for the same reason, but the part of the api around InjectionListener, encounters, types is too verbose. I prefer Spring's BeanPostProcessor that's simply invoked with an object.

Comment: Another point in favor of Spring: Implementing a BeanPostProcessor makes it very easy to replace the injectee with a proxy or a wrapper / decorator.